# Getting invalid regular expression flag after running the program

Tags: ecmascript-6

I am practicing ES6 on freeCodeCamp. Currently, I am solving a problem related to topic **Template Literals**. The problem statement is like

> Use template literal syntax with *backticks* to display each entry of the *result* object's *failure* array. Each entry should be wrapped inside a *li* element with the class attribute *text-warning*, and listed within the *resultDisplayArray*.

After executing the code all test cases are passed except one

> Template strings were used

and I am getting the error

> Invalid regular expression flags

Please see below code and tell me where I am doing wrong.

```
const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["id-blacklist", "no-dup-keys"]
};
function makeList(arr) {
  "use strict";

  // change code below this line
  const resultDisplayArray = arr.map(value => 
  `<li class="text-warning">${value}</li>`);
  // change code above this line

  return resultDisplayArray;
}
/**
 * makeList(result.failure) should return:
 * [ <li class="text-warning">no-var</li>,
 *   <li class="text-warning">var-on-top</li>, 
 *   <li class="text-warning">linebreak</li> ]
 **/
const resultDisplayArray = makeList(result.failure);
```

Comment: I've tested your code in console and its working fine without error and showing same result as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you @Karan for replying but all test cases are not passed on freeCodeCamp.
Can you try on the plateform. This is the link
https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/create-strings-using-template-literals

Comment: It is also working for me. Is a developer console giving you the issue, or CodeCamp itself?

Comment: @dandeto codeCamp itself.

Comment: it seems it is a bug of freeCodeCamp. your code is correct. and you are not using regex at all (So regex flag can't be incorrect!). Report to them this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct and clear!

It is a bug at freeCodeCamp as you can see on this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/freeCodeCamp/issues/17788).

Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Guilherme

Comment: Welcome my friend @VivekKumar